# PyLint not getting imports in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, import, pylint

I have a Flask app with the following (typical, I think) structure.

```
repo_name
    config.py
    requirements.txt
    run.py
    /service
       __init__.py
       models.py
       schemas.py
       views.py
```

The `run.py` script has the following content

```
from service import app
app.run(debug=False, port=8080, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Inside `service.__init__.py` I create the Flask app, and at the end, `import views`.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

import service.views
```

The `models.py`, `schemas.py`, and `views.py` are all pretty standard for simple Flask apps, and they also call `from service import app` or `from service import models` as needed.

My problem is that PyLint is throwing the error "E0401: Unable to import 'service'" for all these import calls. This is not really a "legitimate" error because I can run the code just fine.

One thing that makes the error go away is changing the import calls to `from repo_name.service import ...`. However, this is undesirable for two reasons

1. The `repo_name` is not really related to the app. If I were to go this route, I would probably end up moving everything down a directory. Further, there's no requirement that people name the directory the same way (e.g., someone might clone it as `git clone <url> foobar` instead of `git clone <url> repo_name`, which would break code.
2. More importantly, this doesn't even work. When I make those changes and try to run the server, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'repo_name'`.

How can I make reconcile PyLint and Flask here? Ideally I'd like to fix the issue in the "correct" way, instead of just adding a `# pylint: disable=` call in front of each import.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but have you tried using relative imports e.g. `from . import app` i think the `from . import xyz` should import from the current module or `from .. import xyz` from the parent module

Comment: @PJSantoro Got it. That almost works, but when I change `from service import app` in `run.py` to `from . import service`, Python throws `ImportError: cannot import name 'service'`. It works if I just use `import service`, but then PyLint doesn't like that. Not sure why.

Comment: OK - wasn't totally clear on where the error was coming from. In run.py i think `from service import app` should stay the same. at the bottom of the `service.__init__.py ` file i'd use: `from . import views`, or if you're trying to import models.py from views.py i'd do: `from . import models`. I don't use PyLint, but PEP8 won't like any import statement at the bottom of the `service.__init__.py` file, but it is necessary to do it that way

Comment: @PJSantoro Ah, sorry I wasn't clear. I did change all the other imports to be relative like you said, and they are working now, which is great. But PyLint is still complaining about `from service import app` in `run.py`. Changing it to a relative import does not seem to fix the problem like the others.

Comment: Strange... maybe try `from .service import app`? I believe what you currently have is the correct syntax, so perhaps it is something specific to PyLint.

Comment: @PJSantoro I did think of that. PyLint is fine with that, but Python says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '\_\_main\_\_.service'; '\_\_main\_\_' is not a package."